# Clarification questions about Boto Dynamo aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I read this: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html

But I still have a few questions.

In:

```
results = users.scan(
...     age__in=[25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
...     limit=1
... )
```

Questions seeking confirmation:
1) Users is a dynamo table.
2) Age is something like data["age"] when stored. So something like this:

```
def createSwfInDynamo(key,images,text):
    data={}
    data["time"]=five
    data["age"]=25
    newI = swfTable.new_item(id,data["time"], data)
    newI.save()
```

could be scanned with the users.scan.

3) Additionally __ is not the object name but rather it separates the comparison operator. Thus age__in would imply that the column age must be in [25, 26, 27, 28, 29].

4) Limit=1 implies that the user only wants 1 match returned?

5) Lastly I am aware that dynamo only returns the first 1mb or 1000 objects. If I want to get all matches to the scan how can I iterate through that nicely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) 2) yes

3) i have no idea

4) and 5)

assuming there are 100 items in your table and you want to scan the table. You can set limit to 25 and call the scan for 4 times. or you can set limit to 1 and call the scan API for 100 times. In scan response there will be an [LastEvaluatedKey](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-response-LastEvaluatedKey) which you should save and pass to your next scan call as [ExclusiveStartKey](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-ExclusiveStartKey).

For example, if your set limit to 25 then your scan result will contains a LastEvaluatedKey which is a hint for DynamoDB service for finding the 26th item.

example based on the code I borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202340/iterating-through-all-items-in-a-dynamodb-table)

```
def search(table, scan_filter=None, range_key=None,
           attributes_to_get=None,
           limit=None):

    start_key = None

    while True:
        results = self.conn.layer1.scan(table_name=table,
                                  attributes_to_get=attributes_to_get,
                                  exclusive_start_key=start_key,
                                  limit=request_limit)
        # do stuff with your results

        start_key = results['LastEvaluatedKey']
        if start_key is None:
            break
```

I would suggest you use the low-level Python API for dynamoDB for now as it is more similar to the Java API and you can get more information online about the basic API. Once you are more comfortable you can move to higher level API which makes you more productive.

Comment: do you have an example of lastEvaluatedKey? ty

Comment: great thanks. Anychance you know why the example http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html where it's let's say age__in works, but advertiser__eq="iTunes...." fails with a scan() got an unexpected keyword argument 'advertiser__eq' when the table has a column advertiser, and that column has a value "iTunes...."

Comment: Also where / what is the lower level python api

Comment: low level api in in the link that you sent. it is on the left navigation bar http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html

Answer (score 0):

1. `users` is the table
2. "This is correct age" is the variable name

   I found this [here](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/433f211b5eb93560916a4bd4a1dbf905e6c13a58/boto/dynamodb2/table.py).

   After checking the source code it appears to split the arguments by the `__`.
3. Thus, yes, the ending is the argument `/` operator in this case.
4. True
5. Solution given by @Erben Mo